# Could I be a contest bodybuilder without drugs?

Tags: muscle, bodybuilding

I'm wondering if I could participate in bodybuilding contests without drugs.

I have been focusing lately on muscular size and development while stringently, making sure I don't increase bodyfat (and so far it's actually working, but it's very time consuming). I am not super lean, but I'm far from being fat -- which makes me think I could turn a few heads in, say, local bodybuilding contests.

I don't plan on winning any, but I do know that I have almost no chance at winning when other competitors will almost assuredly be using enhancements that I won't.

Basically, can I get any recognition in the bodybuilding world being 100% natural? I'm not asking to be Mr. Olympia -- I just want to know if I can make it anywhere being 100% natural (no AAS, PEDs, SARMs, Clen, prohoromones, or etc.) in bodybuilding/fitness/physique world.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

There are tested competitions alongside untested.

Comment: Damn, beat me to it

Comment: Sometimes an answer can be this simple.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on JJosaur's answer, I can personally attest to drug free competitions.  I was a drug free competitive bodybuilder, and, I successfully competed locally (in my state) and at locations in the US.  The competitions were sanctioned by a specific Natural Bodybuilding organization.   The testing typically involved urine and/or lie detector before the event.  Granted, it’s not a fool proof method, and things may have changed since I “retired”, but, it was what was used by many organizations.  The one thing you must understand is that training drug free is a much more difficult challenge.  You must be smarter, and, be prepared to train for many years paying close attention to detail (nutrition, rest, etc.) in order to maximize any potential you may have.